# One label only for align in empheq

Tags: equations, align, labels, empheq

I am using the `empheq` package and use `align` environement insied of it. For instance,

```
\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
a&=b \\
E&=mc^2 + \int_a^a x\, dx
\end{empheq}
```

or

```
\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
 a&=b &&t\\
E&=mc^2 + \int_a^a x\, dx&&y
\end{empheq}
```

With this syntax I obtain one label per line:

[image: result]

or

[image]

Is there any possibility, to only obtain one label for the two lines (located at the middle position between labels (3) and (4) (or (1) and (2))?

Comment: Almost, but In practice I use `align` with many alignment conditions per line (I add a new example in my original post)

Comment: Anyway, your code is not compilable, please make a complete MWE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`empheq` is about numbering *all* lines. You don't need it for this case.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\left\{
  \begin{aligned}
  a&=b \\
  E&=mc^2 + \int_a^a x\, dx
  \end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation}
followed by another one
\begin{equation}
\left\{
  \begin{alignedat}{2}
  a&=b                      &\hspace{4em}& t\\
  E&=mc^2 + \int_a^a x\, dx && y
  \end{alignedat}
\right.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I understand. Thank you